# Zeal Smart Members - Reset Password form while logged in

Tags: members, password

We're using EE3 and Zeal Smart Members to handle the login, reset password etc.. functionality.

Is there a way to use the Reset Password form while logged in?

Currently the Reset password for seems to detect that your logged in and just displays the message "You are already logged in"

Answer (score 0):

Under **mod.smart_members.php** file go to **reset_password** function and comment out first if condition. that will now allow you to reset password while logged_in.

[image: smart members reset password while logged_in]